# update new data but do not remove previous data table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my table

```
----------
id     | user_id  | sid  | fid  | channel




----------
1     | 10usl1 | 1029298 | null | snapdeal
```

i have update fid and channel flipkart then channel field remove the snapdeal but i want snapdeal,flipkart

update query do not remove snapdeal for channel field
please help me

This my code

```
public function set_response_data($id,$data){       
        $whereCondtions = array(
               'user_id' =>$this->user_id,
               'id' => $id);
        $this->db->where($whereCondtions);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
        return $id;}
```

Comment: Plz use commas and dot to make your question readable.

Comment: Please make you question clear

Comment: i wan update FID field and channel field , The channel field dont remove previus value

Answer (score 0):

Sql query For your question

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET `channel` = CONCAT($data['val'], ' , ',channel), `fid` = $data['fid'] WHERE $whereCondtions;
```

IN codeigniter You just send channel value in concat form...

Like `$data['val'] = CONCAT('snapdeal', ' , ',channel)`

Concat function use for concatenate two string in mysql

Comment: Thank you for replay                                                                         but your solution is not working because last value i am not getting (snapdeal)

Comment: CONCAT('snapdeal', ' , ',channel)  -- -- In this snapdeal is latest value which you want update and channel is coloum name. Again try it.. It will be working fine, I know in every case(one or multiple coloum).. You can run query direct in database. @Nepster